# How to pass `this` to Dozer field mapping?

Tags: java, dozer

In my app I have Dozer mapping which looks like this:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>java.util.HashMap</class-a>
    <class-b>org.mycompany.TargetClass</class-b>
    <field custom-converter="org.example.MyConverter">
        <a>this</a>
        <b>anotherField</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

`MyConverter` is an instance of `ConfigurableCustomConverter`:

```
public class MyConverter implements ConfigurableCustomConverter {

    private String parameter;

    @Override
    public Object convert(
            Object existingDestinationFieldValue,
            Object sourceFieldValue,
            Class<?> destinationClass,
            Class<?> sourceClass) {
        // sourceClass is always java.lang.Object and
        // sourceFieldValue is always null!!!
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameter(String parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }
}
```

Why things noted in in-source comment happen?

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell dozer which key of the Map should be mapped to `b.anotherField`, with something like

```
<field custom-converter="org.example.MyConverter">
    <a key="foobar">this</a>
    <b>anotherField</b>
</field>
```

See http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mapbackedproperty.html#Mapping_Class_Level_Properties_to_a_java.util.Map_or_a_Custom_Map_with_unique_GetSet_methods

Comment: But is there a way to pass mapped object (or map) itself, instead of a distinct field?

Comment: "this" was a godsend. Thanks