# Converting j8583 object having one getter with params in Dozer

Tags: java, dozer, j8583

I have an IsoMessage object (https://github.com/chochos/j8583/blob/master/src/main/java/com/solab/iso8583/IsoMessage.java) that has an internal array which I can only access through a getField(int) method.

```
public class IsoMessage {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private IsoValue[] fields = new IsoValue[129];
    .........
    .........
    .........

    /** Returns the IsoValue for the specified field. First real field is 2. */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> IsoValue<T> getField(int field) {
        return fields[field];
    }
```

I need to read all the attributes stored on the fields array, by calling getField(param Number), and move them to a new object that has a Map, and want to achieve this using dozer.

the object that I need to translate to:

```
public class TransactionInstance implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3429335891821913088L;
    private String transactionName;
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
```

I was experimenting with this dozer configuration hoping to get the field 1 from my isoMessage object

```
<mapping map-id="a">
    <class-a>com.solab.iso8583.IsoMessage</class-a>
    <class-b>j8583.example.TransactionInstance</class-b>
    <field>
        <a get-method="getField" key="1">field</a>
        <b map-set-method="put">parameters</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

But I'm stuck at getting the value from the original object with this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.dozer.MappingException: No read or write method found for field (field) in class (class com.solab.iso8583.IsoMessage)
    at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.determinePropertyType(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:319)
    at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:76)
    at org.dozer.fieldmap.MapFieldMap.determineActualPropertyType(MapFieldMap.java:170)
    at org.dozer.fieldmap.MapFieldMap.getSrcFieldValue(MapFieldMap.java:95)
```

I was checking this post https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/111 and [How to pass `this` to Dozer field mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656606/how-to-pass-this-to-dozer-field-mapping) bus still stuck in the same place, also I was wondering if I can achieve this by using the API so I can tell dynamically which fields I want to get from the original bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally foud the rigth mapping using the capability that dozer has to access the internal objects directly (http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html).

```
<mapping>
    <class-a is-accessible="true">com.solab.iso8583.IsoMessage</class-a>
    <class-b>j8583.example.TransactionInstance</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>fields[3]</a>
        <b set-method="addParameter" map-set-method="addParameter" key="field3">parameters
        </b>
    </field>

</mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Dozer, but field 1 is the bitmap. `getField(1)` returns `null`.

Comment: your are right, but in this case we are no getting inside the isoMessage object yet, we are triying to first access the method or the j8583 fields on dozer to convert them into a internal bussines POJO